# How can I store in a batch script a custom variable as the name of the field to add

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a pattern in firebase of type many to many. 
A user can have a set of friends, which are structured in Firebase as follows:

```
<friends-collection>
    <user-id>{
        FdiIcNy8dYCxUjjC9D0w: true
        GjMTvIctZCYJvNLZPH4r: true
    }
```

**Each name of a new field is the identifier of a document**

I tried to do it as follows:

```
const petitionerFriendsRef = db.doc('friends/${request.petitioner.id}');
    batch.set(petitionerFriendsRef,
        {
        request.requested.id: true,
        },
        { merge: true }
    );
```

But it is clearly not a valid option.

There are a few examples in firebase such as:

```
let nycRef = db.collection('cities').doc('NYC');
batch.set(nycRef, {name: 'New York City'});
```

But in none of them do they add a custom variable to the field name

After having made several queries on google, I can't find any example of this operation on a batch write. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Firestore.  You can just use JavaScript syntax to use the value of an expression as the property of an object.

```
batch.set(petitionerFriendsRef, {
    [request.requested.id]: true,
},
    { merge: true }
);
```

Note the use of square brackets around `request.requested.id`